# Dividing signal into frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, sampling, divide

I am working on a simple internet radio app in iOS with a very simple speech/music discrimination. The main idea is a radio which plays a signal from url and at the same time it checks what type of signal is being broadcast. When it detects a speech it change the channel and so on.

I wonder how can read sampling frequency from signal in iOS and how to divide signal from URL into frames. I know I should use something from Core Audio, but I'm quite new in iOS and can't find it.